# JSF 2.2 Form Submit, reloading page = resubmit?

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

So i have a JSF Application. If i submit a form, it gets resubmitted when i refresh the page. and of course i don't want that.

Index.xhtml:

```
[...]
    <h:form >
        <h:outputText value="Form"/><br/>
        <h:inputText label="first" value="#{example.newExample.firstWord}" autocomplete="off"></h:inputText>
         <h:commandButton value="click" actionListener="#{example.NewExample()}">        

         </h:commandButton>

    </h:form>
[...]
```

The method that gets runned:

```
  public void NewExample(){
    pfDB.InsertNewExample(NewExample);
    NewExample.setFirstWord(null);
    NewExample.setSecondWord(null);
}
```

So everytime i refresh index.xhtml after i submitted the form, NewExample() get runned.

Comment: So, do you mean that NewExample() is called twice? (also, remember that in java, the convention is that the first letter of a method should be in lower case)

Comment: No it is called if i manually refresh the page after the submission off the form

Comment: That's because POST requests are submitted again when you refresh the page. Your web browser probably alerts you that the data will be sent again and asks you to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was indeed the resubmitting off the form that was the problem. But the browser(opera) didn't showed an alert.

I fixed it by adding

```
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
```

in my function